# Eliminar caracteres de varias variables que cumplen un patrón en una base de datos en R

Tags: r, funciones, rstudio, substr

tengo una base de datos sobre la cual debo renombrar estas variables, las mismas cumplen un patrón en el final de los caracteres, lo que intento hacer es eliminar los últimos 3 para agregar la información que necesito, pero al momento de correr el código no me presenta error pero no modifica las variables.

Este es el código:

```
modificar_variable <- function(columna) {
  nueva_variable <- paste0(substr(columna, 1, nchar(columna)-3))
  return(nueva_variable)
}

nuevos_caracteres <- function(valor) {
  nuevo_valor <- paste0(valor, "0_45")
  return(nuevo_valor)
}

vector = list("Prótesis_prescripción_45",             
                "Prótesis_prescripción_3")

for (col in vector) {
  mydata1[, col] <- modificar_variable(mydata1[, col], nuevos_caracteres)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

Si entiendo bien, lo que quieres hacer es lo siguiente:

- Con la función `modificar_variable` eliminar los tres últimos caracteres de la variable
- Con la función `nuevos_caracteres`añadir el término `0_45_`

Si es así, lo que deberías hacer es aplicar primero la función `modificar_variable` y posteriormente la función `nuevos_caracteres`

Para ello, el código debería ser:

```
# Variables a cambiar (en modo vector, no lista)
  vector = c("Prótesis_prescripción_45", "Prótesis_prescripción_3")

# Cambiar las variables
  for (col in vector) {
     mydata1[, col] <- nuevos_caracteres(modificar_variable(mydata1[, col])
  }
```

En cualquier caso, con un ejemplo reproducible sería más fácil poder dar una respuesta más precisa a tu consulta. Si es posible, modifica la pregunta añadiendo un ejemplo de los datos según los tienes y lo que esperas que salga.